# Excel: Runtime error 13 type mismatch

Tags: vba, excel

I got Run-time error '13' at then end of this code, even if I try to switch between the commented lines of code

```
Public Property Get cnnString() As String
'old: strcnnString = "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Password="""";User ID=Admin;Data Source=" & Me.DBFolderName & ";Mode=Share Deny Write;Extended Properties="""";Jet OLEDB:System database="""";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="""";Jet OLEDB:Database Password="""";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="""";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;Jet OLEDB:Support Complex Data=False"
'strcnnString = "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Password="""";User ID=Admin;Data Source=" & Me.DBFolderName & ";Mode=Share Deny Write;Extended Properties="""";Jet OLEDB:System database="""";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="""";Jet OLEDB:Database Password="""";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="""";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;Jet OLEDB:Support Complex Data=False"
'new code before edits: strcnnString = "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=" & folder_name & ";Mode=Share Deny None;Extended Properties="""";Jet OLEDB:System database="""";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="""";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=1;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="""";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False "
strcnnString = "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Password="""";User ID=Admin;Data Source=" & Me.DBFolderName & ";Mode=Share Deny Write;Extended Properties="""";Jet OLEDB:System database="""";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="""";Jet OLEDB:Database Password="""";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="""";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;Jet OLEDB:Support Complex Data=False"
cnnString = strcnnString
End Property
```

here is the rest of the code

```
Private strcnnString As String
Private folder_name As String

Public Property Get DBFolderName() As String
 DBFolderName = folder_name
End Property

Public Property Let DBFolderName(ByVal newvalue As String)
folder_name = newvalue
End Property

'calling the property which rais the error
  With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=Array(Me.cnnString), Destination:=Range("A1"))
```

Any solution please?

Comment: Can you confirm Me.DBfolderName returns a string type - as well as what line is making the property call e.g. what you are returning it to accepts a string.

Comment: I edit the question as answer to your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suspect your connection string, here is a good place to look: http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel-2007

Or try:

```
strcnnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Password="""";User ID=Admin;Data Source=" & Me.DBFolderName & ";"
```

EDIT re Comment

I am not quite sure I get you, but perhaps you mean:

```
strcnnString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=" &  Me.DBFolderName & ";"
```

EDIT More notes

I cannot quite see why you are using Array(cnnString), how about:

```
 ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add Connection:=cnnString, Destination:=Range("A1")
```

Comment: the strcnnString value which you provide solved this problem, but raised other issue: run error '1004' "application-defined or object-defined error"

my problem here is I switch code from working with excel 2007 to work with 2003 so as there is no connections in excel 2007 so I used queryTable object instead and now my problem is how to replace the connection string ,the old one is in the question with "'old:" prefix, than you for support

Answer (score 1):

QueryTables.Add can accept a couple of things, but I am not sure an Array is one of them, can you try just passing it the connection string without placing it within an array.